# how to categorise data depending upon a category column in another worksheet and displaying them in a new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-science

I want to use the column 'Qual' in Table 1 and categorise them according to the 'Level' in Table 2 in a separate worksheet, further displaying a separate column 'Qual level' of those levels in table 1

Table1:

| ID | Qual |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | a |
| 3454 | b |
| 2767 | c |
| 2098 | a |

Table2:

| Qual | level |
| --- | --- |
| a | AA |
| b | BB |
| c | CC |

Final output required:

| ID | Qual | Qual Level |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | a | AA |
| 3454 | b | BB |
| 2767 | c | CC |
| 2098 | a | AA |

this is what I have tried so far:

```
df.groupby(['Qual','Level'])['Qual Level']
```

its been giving me an error and im not sure if this is the right method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical join operation. You can use pd.merge:

`new_df = df.merge(other_df, on='Qual', how='left')`

Then to rename the `level` column,

`new_df = new_df.rename(columns={'level': 'Qual Level'})`

Answer (score 0):

You can try `pd.merge`

```py
df1['Qual Level'] = df1.merge(df2, on='Qual', how='left')['level']
```

```
print(df1)

     ID Qual Qual Level
0  1234    a         AA
1  3454    b         BB
2  2767    c         CC
3  2098    a         AA
```

Comment: both the tables are in the same file on separate sheets.
Do I need to assign the tables separately if so how?

Comment: @JibranKhatib Sorry, I don't quite understand what does it means.

Comment: the data in table 1 and table 2 are both in one excel sheet.
since you have defined df1 and df2. do i need to assign the tables as such ?

Comment: yes, we assumed you have already loaded the tables in as separate dataframes

Comment: `df1` is the dataframe converted from your table 1, `df2` is the dataframe converted from your table 2.